# More than the specified no. of columns are renamed with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I  joined multiple files using Pandas join() but now want to rename a few of the duplicate columns. But when I specify the indices to rename a few columns, more than the specified no. of columns are being renamed.

Input CSV files have the format

```
F1.csv
A,B,C,D,E,F
1,4,5,6,7,8
2,1,3,4,5,6
3,4,1,5,1,8
4,5,1,5,6,7

F2.csv
A,B,C,M,N
1,4,5,6,7
2,1,3,4,5
3,4,1,5,1
4,5,1,5,6

F3.csv 
A,B,C,X,Y,Z
1,4,5,6,7,8
2,1,3,4,5,6
3,4,1,5,1,8
4,5,1,5,6,7

F4.csv
A,B,C,T,Q,R
1,4,5,6,7,8
2,1,3,4,5,6
3,4,1,5,1,8
4,5,1,5,6,7
```

And my code

```
data = None

for f in filelist:
    if data is None:
            data = pandas.read_csv(f, index_col='A')
    else:
            data = data.join(pandas.read_csv(f, index_col='A'), lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right', how=join_type)

print(list(data))  

new_names =["HH","XX"]
old_names = data.columns[[0,1]]
data.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)), inplace=True)
print(list(data_union))
```

The  first print gives the output

```
 ['B_left', 'C_left', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'B_right', 'C_right', 'M', 'N', 'B_left', 'C_left', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'B_right', 'C_right', 'T', 'Q', 'R']
```

And print after renaming gives

```
['HH', 'XX', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'B_right', 'C_right', 'M', 'N', 'HH', 'XX', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'B_right', 'C_right', 'T', 'Q', 'R']
```

My problem is instead of renaming columns at indices 0 and 1 alone, it is changing indices 10 and 11 too.  Could anyone help me with this? I am new to Pandas and not able to figure this out. Thanks,

Comment: What's the difference between data and data_union?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, there is not difference. I edited data_union to data.